# Proper way of starting game again in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm developing a little game and I need your help with one thing. In my game, when the user loses all of his lives, sees a Game Over screen. There, there is a button to replay the game that takes the user to the main scene again. The problem is that doing this increases the memory consumption every time. I've seen that I might be creating an instance of the scene every time the user plays the game, so I would like to know the proper way to do this in SpriteKit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's hard to help you here, when it's not clear what you are currently doing. "I might be...." ?  It's fundamental to expect more memory to be consumed if you are creating a new instance of your scene each time.

Answer (score 0):

You must have **Model** if you working with game app, and **Singleton** object(where you add special methods for game moments and current instances), i'm thinking... If you have it, you can add boolValue for checking. For example

```
if (gameModel.instance != nil) {
resumeGame = YES;
} else {
resumeGame = NO;
}
```

Maybe answer is rude, but question is difficult to understand, when no examples...

Answer (score 0):

memory consumption can occur due to many cases in sprite kit

1) you are fetching same texture again and again from memory

2) your instance of the scene is not properly removed from the spritekit memory

first fetch your graphics only once and save them in a singleton variable
  for eg

static SKTextureAtlas *gameAtlas=nil;

```
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
 //fetch gameAtlas only once once for class not for instance

});
```

3)set all strong reference to nil recreating a scene again